# How to Add a Custom Line Connect Provider to Strapi v4

Tags: strapi

I followed https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-o-auth2-open-id-connect-provider-to-strapi-v4 and replaced 'trackmania' with 'line' (which already exists).

So I went ahead and edited `node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/bootstrap/grant-config.js`.
[image: grant-config.js]

As well as `node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/services/providers-registry.js`

[image: provider-registry.js]

However, I still encounter issues:

[image: error]

Comment: I dont know `strapi`, but I do know you're not supposed to edit the files under `node_modules`. I imagine this is where your trouble might have started.

Comment: RateLimitError suggests to me that you're making too many requests in a certain time. Might be another problem.